# Incomplete Data Transfer from VBA to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have a SQL-Server in Azure and want to transfer data from Excel into it using VBA through a VPN Tunnel. It works but out of 801 entries sometimes 320 are transmitted sometimes 324 but always in a range between 300 and 350 never more. They are transfer in the correct order as they are in the excel file. I am not getting an error at all. Just saw in the SQL Table that there are not all entries in there. I tried it some times and colleagues of my as well with the same result. My code is:

```
Sub Importer(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal importQuery As String, pass As String)

    Dim con As Object
    
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
        con.Open _
                "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};" & _
                "Server=tcp:myServer,1433;" & _
                "Database=myDB;" & _
                "Uid= admin;" & _
                "Pwd=" & pass & ";" & _
                "TrustServerCertificate=no;" & _
                "Connection Timeout=30;" & _
                "Encrypt=yes;"
        con.Execute importQuery
        con.Close
       
    Set con = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

While importQuery contails 801 INSERT INTO entries in one query looking like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table(Variable1, Variable1, Variable1) Values(", 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.table(Variable1, Variable1, Variable1) Values(", 3)
INSERT INTO dbo.table(Variable1, Variable1, Variable1) Values(", 3)
```

...

I tried to set the timeout up but with no effect. Anyone with an idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: What does `importQuery` contain? You're asking why the SQL query stored in that variable fails. People can't even guess without knowing what the query actually does

Comment: Besides, unless the query contains a `BULK INSERT` command that only works with *text* files, `importQuery` is most likely one or more `INSERT`s with values for one or more rows. Does it actually contain what you assume?

Comment: Good hint. I added the content of the importQuery variable.

Comment: So you have 801 separate Insert statements?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't explain what you're doing. Right now there's very little information. What you posted is pseudo-code that inserts a single row, not 800 or 300. Are you executing that methos 800 times? Or does the query contain 800 inserts? What is the *real* query?

Comment: I create for each row in excel one INSERT INTO so in the importQuery I have 801 Insert Into statements.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the Insert statements one by one?

Comment: @FunThomas That works but takes a very long time

Comment: Don't close the connection between the single statements. Shouldn't take much more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is syntactically incorrect, but that's irrelevant I guess.

Currently you're doing multiple singleton `INSERT` statements in an non-transactional manner. Surely your connection is being broken or some other issue happens in the middle of the code executing, resulting in only some of the data being inserted.

Either wrap a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) around the entire set of `INSERT` statements. Or even simpler would be to convert them to a single `INSERT` statement of multiple values, which will be implicitly transactional and potentially more efficient, like so:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table(Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES
    (ValueA1, ValueA2, ValueA3),
    (ValueB1, ValueB2, ValueB3),
    (ValueC1, ValueC2, ValueC3),
    (ValueD1, ValueD2, ValueD3),
    (ValueE1, ValueE2, ValueE3);
```

As far as whatever error / issue your application is running into, unfortunately won't be advisable without more details such as a specific error message. But at least the fix I mentioned above will ensure either all or none of the data is consistently inserted.